# Weird behaviour when making css transition flow from the right

Tags: html, css

So I want to make it so that in my navbar when you hover over a link a line comes from the bottom left and top right yet when I make the line come from the right the link changes size and other weird stuff how can I fix this?

```css
* {
  margin : 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav{
background-color: black;
width: 1200px;
height: 110px;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
}

ul{
  left: 0;
}

.nav{
  position: relative;
}

.navlink{
  margin-right: 14px;
}

.navlink1{
  margin-right: 14px;
  margin-left: 14px;
}

.navlink4{
margin-right: 0;
}

.navlink::before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 5px;
  background:darkred;
  transition: width .5s;
  float: right;
}

.navlink:hover::before{
  width: 100%;
  transition: width .5s;
}

.navlink::after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 5px;
  background:darkred;
  transition: width .5s;
}

.navlink:hover::after{
  width: 100%;
  transition: width .5s;
}

.navlink1::before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 5px;
  background:darkred;
  transition: width .5s;
}
 
li{
display: inline-block;
}

li a{
  display: inline-block;
 background-color: #FFDA45;
 border: black solid 1px;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 20px;
 width: 235px;
 margin-top: 11px;
 margin-bottom: 11px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size: 200%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    
 <ul class="nav">
   <li><a class="navlink" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a class="navlink" href="TLOU part II.html">TLOU part II</a></li>
   <li><a class="navlink" href="Video's.html">Video's</a></li>
   <li><a class="navlink" href="Music.html">Music</a></li>
 </ul>
 
</nav>
```

So I used float: right; to make the before element come from the right yet for some reason this causes the link to behave weird.

here is how it works without float: right;

```css
    * {
      margin : 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    nav{
    background-color: black;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 110px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    }

    ul{
      left: 0;
    }

    .nav{
      position: relative;
    }

    .navlink{
      margin-right: 14px;
    }

    .navlink1{
      margin-right: 14px;
      margin-left: 14px;
    }

    .navlink4{
    margin-right: 0;
    }

    .navlink::before{
      content: '';
      display: block;
      width: 0;
      height: 5px;
      background:darkred;
      transition: width .5s;
    }

    .navlink:hover::before{
      width: 100%;
      transition: width .5s;
    }

    .navlink::after{
      content: '';
      display: block;
      width: 0;
      height: 5px;
      background:darkred;
      transition: width .5s;
    }

    .navlink:hover::after{
      width: 100%;
      transition: width .5s;
    }

    .navlink1::before{
      content: '';
      display: block;
      width: 0;
      height: 5px;
      background:darkred;
      transition: width .5s;
    }
     
    li{
    display: inline-block;
    }

    li a{
      display: inline-block;
     background-color: #FFDA45;
     border: black solid 1px;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 20px;
     width: 235px;
     margin-top: 11px;
     margin-bottom: 11px;
     text-align: center;
     font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
     font-size: 200%;
    }
```

```html
    <nav>
        
     <ul class="nav">
       <li><a class="navlink" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a class="navlink" href="TLOU part II.html">TLOU part II</a></li>
       <li><a class="navlink" href="Video's.html">Video's</a></li>
       <li><a class="navlink" href="Music.html">Music</a></li>
     </ul>
     
    </nav>
```

So I want it to look like that but with the top one coming from the right side.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this with background. Simply adjust the position and size like you want:

```
li a {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(darkred,darkred) bottom 5px left  5px,
    linear-gradient(darkred,darkred) top    5px right 5px,
    #FFDA45;
  background-size:0% 8px; /* width:0 height:8px */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:0.5s;
}
li a:hover {
  /* full width minus 5px from left and right */
  background-size:calc(100% - 10px) 8px;
}
```

Full code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: black;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 110px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

ul {
  left: 0;
}
.nav {
  position: relative;
}

.navlink {
  margin-right: 14px;
}


li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(darkred,darkred) bottom 5px left  5px,
    linear-gradient(darkred,darkred) top    5px right 5px,
    #FFDA45;
  background-size:0% 8px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:0.5s;
  border: black solid 1px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 235px;
  margin-top: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 200%;
}
li a:hover {
  background-size:calc(100% - 10px) 8px;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a class="navlink" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="TLOU part II.html">TLOU part II</a></li>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="Video's.html">Video's</a></li>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="Music.html">Music</a></li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```